# change document.createElement('div') to document.createDocumentFragment()

Tags: javascript, dom

```
const allItemContainer = document.getElementById("all-items");
data.pizza.forEach((item) => {
        let container = document.createElement("div");
        //container will contain <div class='shop-item'>
        container.classList.add("shop-item");
        container.id = item.id; //will add an id to the current div equal to the ID given in the json file
        let textHeading = document.createElement("span");
        textHeading.classList.add("shop-item-title");
        textHeading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.name));
}
container.appendChild(textHeading);
allItemContainer.appendChild(container);
});
```

I wish to change the `document.createElement()` to `document.createDocumentFragment()`. I tried changing it but I got an error:-
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`
How do I add classList to this Fragment? I'm new to this. Please help.

Comment: A document fragment is not an element, so it doesn't have classes. A fragment is basically just a temporary container for other elements. When you add a fragment to an existing element, it "unwraps" and its children get added instead. Sounds like you may not actually want a document fragment? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment#usage_notes

Comment: Due to performance reasons, I wanted to shift to fragment. Now, is there no way I can add a class to this and make the UI look like earlier?

Comment: Appending to a document fragement instead of a detached(!) `div` won't make a difference. What *might* make a difference is delaying adding each container to the document till the very end, for which you can indeed use a fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `DocumentFragments` are not HTML elements, So you can't add class on it. It is like a container that is used to append a child to it. It is in memory and it is not part of a DOM tree. So when you append child on `DocumentFragments`, it doesn't change the flow of the DOM tree. Append elements to the document fragment and then append the document fragment to the DOM tree.

> In the DOM tree, the document fragment is replaced by all its children. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

As per MDN

> DocumentFragments are DOM Node objects which are never part of the main DOM tree. The usual use case is to create the document fragment, append elements to the document fragment and then append the document fragment to the DOM tree. In the DOM tree, the document fragment is replaced by all its children.

```js
const data = {
  pizza: [{
      id: "100",
      name: "pizza1"
    },
    {
      id: "101",
      name: "pizza2"
    },
    {
      id: "102",
      name: "pizza3"
    },
    {
      id: "103",
      name: "pizza4"
    },
  ],
};

const allItemContainer = document.getElementById("all-items");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

data.pizza.forEach((item) => {
  let container = document.createElement("div");
  //container will contain <div class='shop-item'>
  container.classList.add("shop-item");
  container.id = item.id; //will add an id to the current div equal to the ID given in the json file
  let textHeading = document.createElement("span");
  textHeading.classList.add("shop-item-title");
  textHeading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.name));
  container.appendChild(textHeading);
  fragment.appendChild(container);
});

allItemContainer.appendChild(fragment);
```

```css
.shop-item {
  padding: .5rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="all-items"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Due to performance reasons, I wanted to shift to fragment

Your code isn't valid, but I assume the `allItemContainer.appendChild(container);` call is inside the `forEach` callback. If so, and if adding these elements really causes a performance issue, then you might be able to improve this by adding each container to a fragment and insert the fragment at the end to only cause a single reflow (instead of triggering a reflow for every container):

```
const allItemContainer = document.createDocumentFragement();

data.pizza.forEach((item) => {
    let container = document.createElement("div");
    //container will contain <div class='shop-item'>
    container.classList.add("shop-item");
    container.id = item.id; //will add an id to the current div equal to the ID given in the json file
    let textHeading = document.createElement("span");
    textHeading.classList.add("shop-item-title");
    textHeading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.name));
    container.appendChild(textHeading);
    allItemContainer.appendChild(container);
});

document.getElementById("all-items").appendChild(allItemContainer);
```